# julia child pot au feu recipe

Tags: french-cuisine

For Julia Child's Pot au Feu recipe in MTAFC, the final instruction is to separate the vegetables, meat and stock, and "pass the stock along" with any of a list of optional sauces.

Is the dinner guest supposed to just add some of the sauce in their bowl along with the soup/stew mixture when it's all assembled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pot au Feu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pot-au-feu) is traditionally served as two and sometimes even three courses, bone-marrow on toast, soup & 'solids'. You can serve them up simultaneously if you wish & your diners can sample each course as they prefer.

Good illustration & recipe ideas at [SpruceEats](https://www.thespruceeats.com/pot-au-feu-recipe-1375558) -

[image]